# How do i make a code return to the start in C

Tags: c, loops, nested-loops, do-while

I'm currently trying to make a number pseudo calculator of sorts that is supposed to add any number of integers until a negative is given then sum the amount of integers added, the biggest, smallest, average and also count the numbers of integers given. I have managed to make all of that, now im supposed to loop it without using a infinite loop, i have tried several hours but i just cant figure it out. I tried making the code return to the start but that doesn't seem to work. I'm wondering if it's possible to make the code return to the start or if another way to make it loop exist.

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <stdlib.h>

int main(void)
{
    int number = 0;
    int big = -1;
    int small = -1;
    float average = 0;
    int sum = 0;
    int counter = 0;

    do
    {
    

printf("Enter a number: ");
        scanf_s("%d", &number);

        if (number < 0)
            break;

        sum += number;

        if (big == -1 || number > big)
        {
            big = number;
        }

        if (small == -1 || number < small)
        {
            small = number;
        }

        counter++;

        average = (float) sum / counter;


        printf("sum =%d, big = %d, small = %d, counter = %d", sum, big, small, counter);
        printf("average = %.2f", average);

    } while (number >= 0);

    int yes = 1;
    int no = 0;
    

    printf("Would you like to run the program again (1 for yes, 0 for no)?: ");
    scanf_s("%d, %d", &yes, &no);

    if (yes == 1 || no != 1)
    {
        goto main;
    }
    else


    return 0;
}
```

Comment: Use a while loop just like your others

Comment: What does "return to the start" mean? If you tried to call `main` recursively, that would be a bad idea. Loops are your friend. Using `goto` is widely frowned upon. Only use it if you have some good reason. Replacing a simple loop is no such reason.

Comment: Aside: I don't get the intention of the last `scanf_s("%d, %d", &yes, &no);`, which requires an input like `1,0` not a simple `1` or `0` requested by the prompt.

Comment: @pmg: "...without using infinite loop". ;)

Comment: As pmg noted, you can extract a method and call that multiple times using a `for` or `while` loop. You would leave the "would you like to run the program again" part in the main loop and use the result of that as exit condition for the loop; you could use `break` for that as well, or a `do...while` construct.

Comment: So...you want to write an infinite loop without writing an infinite loop.  Cannot be done.  Whatever mechanism you use to create the loop will be using an infinite loop.  Whether it is a recursive call to main or a re-exec of the process, when you succeed you will have created an inifinite loop and failed.  You need to be more precise about exactly what you are trying to avoid.  Is any mechanism other than `for` or `while` acceptable?

Comment: @WilliamPursell There is clearly an exit condition at the end of the `main`.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

For starters `main` is not a label So this `goto` statement

```
goto main;
```

does not make a sense. And you should not use the `goto` statement in your programs.

These statements

```
average = (float) sum / counter;

printf("sum =%d, big = %d, small = %d, counter = %d", sum, big, small, counter);
printf("average = %.2f", average);
```

must be moved after the do-while loop.

In this if statement

```
    if (big == -1 || number > big)
    {
        big = number;
    }
```

the expression `big == -1`  is redundant because it is evident that any non-negative number is greater than `-1`.

And you need to enter a value only to one variable in this call of `scanf_s`

```
scanf_s("%d, %d", &yes, &no);
```

That is the call will look like

```
scanf_s("%d", &yes);
```

As for your question when you need to use one more outer do-while or while loop.

For example

```
int yes;

do
{
    do 
    {
        //...
    } while ( number >= 0 );

    average = (float) sum / counter;
    printf("sum =%d, big = %d, small = %d, counter = %d", sum, big, small, counter);
    printf("average = %.2f", average);

    printf("Would you like to run the program again (1 for yes, 0 for no)?: "); 
} while ( scanf_s("%d", &yes ) == 1 && yes == 1 );
```

Also you need to check whether the user at once entered a negative number. In this case for example `counter` will be equal to `0`. In this case you should issue a message that the user did not enter numbers instead of outputting `sum`, `big`, `small`, `counter` and `average`.

Answer (score 2):

The two simplest mechanisms are:

```
int main(void) {
    start:
    /* code here */
    goto start;
    /* ... */
}
```

and

```
int main(void) {
    int yes = 1; int no = 0;
    while( yes == 1 || no == 0 ){
        /* ... */
    }
    /* ... */
}
```

Note that using two flags (`yes` and `no`) is a bit odd.  You probably would rather do something like:

```
char response = 'y';
while( response == 'y' || response == 'Y' ){
    ...
    if( scanf(" %c", &response) != 1 ){
        break;
    }
}
```